# How to write a stylized but OS independent WPF controls. Using Microsoft.Windows.Themes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, windows-10, themes

I am looking for an article that would describe the theory of writing stylized controls that would work under different versions of the OS.
Windows 10, 8, 7, Classic Themes.

I am trying to use the DataGridHeaderBorder class in my XAML code.

If I write like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EhLib.WPF">

... 
          <Grid>
            <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder SortDirection="{TemplateBinding local:DataGridColumnHeaderCell.SortDirection}"
                                        IsHovered="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}"
```

and add the assembly PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll to the References section, then
XAML throws an error.

The tag 'DataGridHeaderBorder' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes'. Line 193 Position 14.  EhLib.WPF   1   C:...Lib.WPF\Themes    C:.....WPF\Themes\Generic.xaml 193 14
If I write like this:

```
 xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
```

then the error disappears, but I can not run the application on Windows 7

At launch, the program itself determines which resource assembly to load and use Aero, Aero2, Luna, Classic or Royale.

Question:
Can I also select the desired assembly and substitute it in a string?

```
  xmlns: theme = "clr-namespace: Microsoft.Windows.Themes; assembly =% PresentationFramework.XXX%"
```

The developer of the final application has the ability to override the style assembly using the line:
   ResourceDictionary Source in .

```
<Application x:Class="EhLibTestApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EhLibTestApp"
             StartupUri="MainForm.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Classic, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/classic.xaml" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If he will use my control, then for the correct reference to the DataGridHeaderBorder class, the control should refer to the selected style assembly.

How to do this correctly taking into account the OS version and Application.Resources ResourceDictionary Source overrides?

I want my controls that use the DataGridHeaderBorder to look the same as the standard WFP controls.
In particular, DataGrid.

The DataGrid header used by the DataGridHeaderBorder looks under different OS and settings in its own way, and it corresponds to the current Windows theme.
If I use a DataGridHeaderBorder in my WPF controls, then it always looks the same, and may not correspond to the Windows theme.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to include `PresentationFramework.Aero2` as part of the application that you deploy to Windows 7? It should be backwards compatible I think.

Comment: I have not tried, but why should I do this.
After all, I want my controls to look the same as the standard ones.
If the program runs on Windows 7, then my controls should look like controls for Windows 7.
If the developer of the final program redefines the styles in Application.Resources.ResourceDictionary and the standard controllers use these overrides, then my controls should also use this override.

Comment: So what is your actual question then?

Comment: I want my controls that use the DataGridHeaderBorder to look the same as the standard WFP controls.
In particular, DataGrid.

The DataGrid header used by the DataGridHeaderBorder looks under different OS and settings in its own way, and it corresponds to the current Windows theme.
If I use a DataGridHeaderBorder in my WPF controls, then it always looks the same, and may not correspond to the Windows theme.

Comment: The n you will need to define a style per theme.

Comment: So do I need to have several Generic.xaml files for each theme?
Generic.Aero.xaml, Generic.Classic.xaml...

How can I choose the correct file to be used for a particular situation (theme)?

Comment: Is there an article somewhere describing how to create components/programs that support multiple themes?

Comment: Sorry, there was no time.
I will check your answer in the coming days.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `ResourceDictionary` per theme in your themes folder provided that your assembly where the controls are defined is marked with the `ThemeInfoAttribute` and have all the other additional characteristics that are described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.themeinfoattribute?view=netcore-3.1):

```
[assembly:ThemeInfoAttribute(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

Your resource dictionaries would then be named something like this:

- themes\luna.normalcolor.xaml
- themes\luna.homestead.xaml
- themes\luna.metallic.xaml
- themes\royale.normalcolor.xaml
- themes\aero.normalcolor.xaml
- themes\classic.xaml

If the resource dictionaries that contain the styles for your controls are defined in a separate assembly from the control classes, you should set the `ResourceDictionaryLocation` of the `ThemeInfoAttribute` to `ResourceDictionaryLocation.ExternalAssembly` and name the external assembly `<YourControlAssembly>.<ThemeName>.dll`. This is what `PresentationFramework.dll` does. It's market with this attribute:

```
[assembly:ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.ExternalAssembly, ResourceDictionaryLocation.None)]
```

And the styles are defined in `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll`, `PresentationFramework.Classic.dll`, etc.

The templates are looked up by naming convention. Besides the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.themeinfoattribute?view=netcore-3.1), you could refer to [Ian Griffith's blog post](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/02/14/wpfdefaulttemplate) for more information about this.

Comment: --
I set ThemeInfo to 
[assembly:ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly, 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly 
)]
to have Generic and theme specific resource dictionaries

--
Then I created 
aero.normalcolor.xaml and classic.xaml

and I transferred theme specific classes to aero.normalcolor.xaml and copy to classic.xaml.

--
It seems that this influenced something, but at run-time system seemed to always select the resource from classic.xaml.

So this does not work as expected.
I tested only in Windows 10.